# Visual Studio Code can't find JDK8

Tags: java, visual-studio, java-8

I am currently trying to compile and run Java in VSC using redhat's extention and the code runner extension, though every time I try to "Run code," it tells me "Java runtime could not be located," and in the output: "'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." So I went into settings to tell VSC the path to my JDK.  I went to "Java configuration" and inserted  "java.home": C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144 into the settings, though it gives me another error stating "Value Expected (2, 18)".  This is where I'm stuck currently:

[image: Where I'm Stuck Currently]

I have also tried the directory to my JDK bin with the same results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do have the same problem and non of the answers helped.

Comment: "java.home": "c:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_161". Slashes must be backwards and doubled.

Comment: Also tried the answers given so far without success. Linux Mint 32-bit. Installed /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161 from tar.gz. Verified runnable in install directory with ./java -version. Specified "java.home": "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161" in both user and workspace settings. Installed all the Language Support and debugger extensions as given. Still have same error as shown in screenshot.

Answer (score 20):

The format of syntax is wrong. Instead of writing -

```
    "java.home": C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
```

this should be written -

```
    "java.home": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144"
```

Use slash (/) instead of backslash () in file path and put quotes around it. Do recheck that jdk 8 or later is installed.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem if you are on Windows machine then open folder
C:\Program Files\Java\  and look for the newest version of JDK in my case it's "jdk1.8.0_144" then enter on the right side following:

```
`{
     "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144"
 }`
```

If you don't have at least 1.8 then install a new one! because VS code doesn't support older versions!

Your error says you need to put in double Slashes.

If you are on Linux then use normal slashes "/"

Don't forget to save and restart VS code afterward to apply changes!
Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by downloading OpenJDK from Red Hat [openjdk](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download/) and placing the extracted file in directory C:\ as in the [image](I have renamed the file name from "java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191-1.b12.redhat.windows.x86_64" to "java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191" for simplicity)
And change user settings in VS Code as [image: USER SETTINGS]
and change workspace settings in VS Code as [image: WORKSPACE SETTINGS]

Answer (score 0):

Please install Java Debugger like RedHat Extension.

These two things are compulsory to install -

1. Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat - already installed .
2. Java Debugger for Visual Studio Code - Install this one .

Here is a shortcut -

vscode:extension/vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Copy and paste above line in the browser address bar and press 'Return(Enter)'. the extension will open in the VSC, Install and reload the editor.

[Go to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582491/debug-run-standard-java-in-visual-studio-code-ide-and-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who ended here with an jdk installed through asdf:

It turned out I did not update my `JAVA_HOME` env variable properly.

Setting it like documented here solved the problem for me: https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java#java_home

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, after a few hours trying to find why it stoped working, came to my solution. Java updated and there was an empty older vesion folder left in the c:\program files\java, just deleted and everything is working again.