# How to run a java code in visual studio code on mac osx?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-11

I am new to coding in VS Code. I want to run a basic "hello world" java program which I'm unable to run.

I installed the java extension pack for vscode.
I have also installed java-11 and maven using homebrew.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I saw few videos where it shows that run and debug buttons pop up in the code editor but those buttons do not pop up in my code.

I can post the screenshots of someone requires it for solving my problem.

I am not able to run the code. Please, someone guide me through the process of running this code.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug/run standard java in Visual Studio Code IDE and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582491/debug-run-standard-java-in-visual-studio-code-ide-and-os-x)

Comment: @Kamil The linked question is about debugging, here it just compiling instead.

Comment: @Aarav Have you read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java and the tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial?

Comment: @Kamil - the query is about running the code to get an output.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I have already read both the tutorial and then installed maven and jdk11 using homebrew. I further installed the required extensions.

Comment: I am unable to share the screenshots here... how to do it..? I tried copying the filepath as the link address but stackoverflow isnt displaying the svreenshots.

Comment: @AaravChandra first answer in this topic is about running code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40570837/5736236